# How to import Krita art into Blender?

Tags: animation, import, blend-files

I downloaded Krita to create a 2d portal for a project. Now I can't figure out how to import the portal into Blender, because none of Krita's file types match any of Blender's import ones. Is an add-on required to connect the two applications?

Comment: Just save as jpg or png and you can import, it all depends on what you want to do with these images

Comment: I'm using the portal as part of a 3d scene. Blender doesn't seem to have a .jpg import option.

Comment: Svg is the only compatible with Blender

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the import/export menus as for importing/exporting 3D data into/out of the scene. You won't find most videos/audio/imagesfile formats there, because it's not the primary way to get any of these in the scene.

The only real exceptions are SVG/PDF formats because it can be converted into mesh data. And you can enable the addon [Import Images As Planes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/addons/import_export/images_as_planes.html), which allows you to automatically create a mesh plane with an image texture on it.

To enable it, go in the menu Edit > Preferences, category Addon, search for it and check its checkbox:

[image]

Then you can use the menu File ‣ Import ‣ Images as Planes, select the image you need to import (or the sequence of images, or the video file), verify the import options in the sidebar, and validate.

If for any reason you want to "import" images manually, they are not imported from that menu at all. Images are most often "mapped" on 3D objects via their material. See [moonboots' answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/311518/53447)

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what you want to do, if you want to import a sequence of images for example, switch your 3D view to *Rendered* or *Material Preview*, activate the *Node Wrangler* addon, create a plane, give it a material, select the *Principled BSDF* and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to get an *Image Texture* plugged into, click on its *Open* button and select your image sequence, the node will switch to *Image Sequence* mode, you now need to tweak the node a bit: enable the *Auto Refresh* option, *Frames* will determine the number of frames of your image sequence you want to play, *Start Frame* will determine when you want the play to begin in the Timeline, and you can Offset the beginning of the sequence with the *Offset* value. When you're good open the *Timeline* and press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to launch. you can keyframe all the node values of course.

[image]